# bootstrap data-dismiss="alert" -- and redirect the other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following PHP and HTML with BS code:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['register']) && $_GET['register'] == 'get') {?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="return refresh('index.php')">×</button>
        <strong>The register must be done with GET!</strong>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

An error is send from register.php to index.php through $_GET superglobal, which is "caught" in index.php with the above code. At this point my URL is `index.php?register=get`. And I want two things:

1. dismiss the div with class="alert" (which is already done)
2. when the little "x" of the alert-danger message is pressed, to reload the page, so that the ?register=get goes away, and the URL to become simply: index.php

Until now I've tried:

1. JS function to call it with "onclick" HTML attribute

   `function refresh(page){
       return window.location.href(page);
   }`
2. `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" id="close1">×</button>`

And I use the following jquery code:

```
$("#close1").on("click", function () {
    window.location.href("http://localhost/ampera/src/supervizor/app/sef_locatie_nou.php");
});
```

I used both absolute and relative path for the jquery code, none worked. And the code only dismisses the alert-danger messages, but not reloading the page as needed.

Comment: which jquery version ur using?

Comment: jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try window.open :

```
window.open("http://localhost/ampera/src/supervizor/app/sef_locatie_nou.php", "_self");
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rj9bR/54/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#close1").on("click", function () {
    location.assign("http://localhost/ampera/src/supervizor/app/sef_locatie_nou.php");
});
```

Comment: nah I've tried it, and ...it's the worse scenario... because when I press the "x", will reload the page with the same alert message and with the same URL.

Comment: remove this onclick="return refresh('index.php')" from html, than add id='close1' for button and then use jquery

Comment: then try location.assign(url);